# How to make box layouts and fit on full screen and full height

Tags: java, android, xml

Height is not fitting in different devices. 
[image: one]

Here is the code:

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <include android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/left_center"
        layout="@layout/card_center_top" />

    <include android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/right_"
        layout="@layout/card_center_right" />

    </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <include android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/left_bottom"
        layout="@layout/card_left_bottom" />

    <include android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/right_bottom"
        layout="@layout/card_right_bottom" />
</LinearLayout>
```

It is not fitting on every device and don't know how to make this happens. Thanks in advance.

Comment: post your code first ?

Answer (score 0):

create below hierarchy. I have set `Black` and `White` box so you can understand easy way.

**Xml Code :**

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/red1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="3">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#FFFFFF"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5">

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#000000"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5">

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#000000"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#FFFFFF"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5">

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#FFFFFF"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5">

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#000000"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5">

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
```

**Output :**

[image]

Comment: Nesting layouts is **bad for performances**. Consider using a single GridView, instead!

Comment: @BipulManjhi visit this how to accept the answer : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

Use relative layout concept

```
<RelativeLayout ..>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Go through this link https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html#Example